# tape archiver and gnuzip

Tags: ubuntu, tar, vpn, quoting, gzip

i have many troubles with installing a vpn client. Now i try to follow another installing list:

There i have to download this archive-file: `anyconnect-predeploy-linux-64-4.3.05017-k9.tar 6.59.23 AM.gz` and extracting the tar archive with `tar xzvf`  But i get the following error message

```
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

What does that mean? Is there a package missing?

Comment: Are you using quotes or escapes? Looks like the filename contains spaces. Try adding quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use quotes:

```
tar -xvzf "anyconnect-predeploy-linux-64-4.3.05017-k9.tar 6.59.23 AM.gz"
```

Or escape all spaces:

```
tar -xvzf anyconnect-predeploy-linux-64-4.3.05017-k9.tar\ 6.59.23\ AM.gz
```